# How to return the "table.column" name on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am needing to do a SQL query that returns on the field the name of the column and the table. Because I am using two tables and need to manipulate them by knowing which table the field belongs to.

Like That:
person.id, person.name, person.adress

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Simple split the strings by `.` to get table and column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the alias to the fully qualified name of the column;

```
SELECT test1.id AS `test1.id`, test2.id AS `test2.id`
...
```

[A simple SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/884b0/1).

Comment: I was thinking in something like this, but your solution is better. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query to get the column names

```
SHOW columns FROM thetable;
```